# Pesquisar em um form e trazer o retorno para o form que chamou

Tags: c#

no meu projeto da faculdade estou fazendo o cadastro de produtos ta tudo certinho o meu problema é carregar o fornecedor no cadastro de produto.
criei um form frmCadastroProduto e um Form frmCadastroFornrcedor no cadastro de produto quando clico em pesquisar o fornecedor abre uma tela de pesquisa e não consigo trazer de volta o fornecedor que selecionei alguém poderia me dar uma força.  Windows Form 4 camadas

segue a baixo

Cadastro de Produto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código

```
  private void pctLocalizaFornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmPesquisarFornecedor pesqFornec = new frmPesquisarFornecedor(this);

        pesqFornec.Show();


    }
```

Pesquisar Fornecedor
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código   o que esta comentado foi o que tentei mais não deu certo

```
   public partial class frmPesquisarFornecedor : Form
{

 //   private int CodFornec;
    //private Form codFornecedor;

    frmCadastroPecas codFornecedor;

    public frmPesquisarFornecedor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public frmPesquisarFornecedor(frmCadastroPecas fm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        codFornecedor = fm1;
        //tbxTextBoxFormB.Text = instanciaDoForm1.tbxTextBoxFormA.Text.ToString();





    }

    //public frmPesquisarFornecedor(int codFornec)
    //{
    //    InitializeComponent();


    //    CodFornec = codFornec;

    //}



    private void frmPesquisarFornecedor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaGrid();

    }


    #region Carregar o Grid Fornecedor
    private void CarregaGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            IList<FornecedorDTO> listaFornecDTO = new List<FornecedorDTO>();

            listaFornecDTO = new FornecedorModel().CargaFornecedor();// Cria uma estancia do Objeto UsuarioModel
            dgvFornecedor.AutoGenerateColumns = false;// Não vai gerar colunas automaticamente
            dgvFornecedor.DataSource = listaFornecDTO;// carrega o meu grid DataSource ListaUsuarioDTO



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void frmPesquisarFornecedor_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        frmCadastroPecas obj = new frmCadastroPecas();


      //  obj.codForn = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoFornec.Text);
    }

    private void dgvFornecedor_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int sel = dgvFornecedor.CurrentRow.Index;

        txtCodigoFornec.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvFornecedor["Codigo", sel].Value);
        txtRazaoSocial.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvFornecedor["NomeRazao", sel].Value);
        txtNomeFantasia.Text = Convert.ToString(dgvFornecedor["NomeFantasia", sel].Value);

    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //PesqFornecDTO objFornec = new PesqFornecDTO();

        //objFornec.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoFornec.Text);

        //frmCadastroPecas obj = new frmCadastroPecas();
        //obj.codForn = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoFornec.Text);

       frmCadastroPecas obj = new frmCadastroPecas();


      //  obj.codForn = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoFornec.Text);

    }




}
```

}

Classe FornecedorDTO

```
public class FornecedorDTO:PessoaDTO
{
    private int codigo;
    private Double vlMinCompra;
    private String telefone2;
    private String contato;
    private int ramal;
    private String userConectado;

    #region Getters e Setters
    public int Codigo
    {
        get { return codigo; }
        set { codigo = value; }
    }

    public String Telefone2
    {
        get { return telefone2; }
        set { telefone2 = value; }
    }
    public String Contato
    {
        get { return contato; }
        set { contato = value; }
    }


    public Double VlMinCompra
    {
        get { return vlMinCompra; }
        set { vlMinCompra = value; }
    }


    public int Ramal
    {
        get { return ramal; }
        set { ramal = value; }
    }


    public String UserConectado
    {
        get { return userConectado; }
        set { userConectado = value; }
    }
```

na tela de pesquisa esta certo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

na tela de peça não esta entrabndo no IF if (retorno == DialogResult.OK)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pq. será ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opá beleza! Tente algo parecido com isso:

```C#
//--- frmPesquisarFornecedor ---
// crie propriedades publicas para retorná-las para frmCadastroDeProduto 
public int RetornoCodigo {get;set;} 
public string RetornoRazaoSocial {get;set;}
// é assim por diante...

//--- frmPesquisarFornecedor ---
private void btnOk_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    this.RetornoCodigo = this.txtCodFornecedorPesquisa.text; // <-- ex: pegando diretamente do textbox
    this.RetornoRazaoSocial = Convert.ToString(dgvFornecedor["NomeRazao", sel].Value); // <-- pegando da grid
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // <-- tem que retornar [OK], para passar no if
    this.Close();
}

//--- frmCadastroDeProduto --- 
private void pctLocalizaFornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form = new frmPesquisarFornecedor())
    {
        var retorno = form.ShowDialog(); // <-- aqui está a magia :D
        if (retorno == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            // os valores vinham como retorno do form assim que ele for fechado
            int codigo = form.RetornoCodigo;
            string razaoSocial = form.RetornoRazaoSocial;

            // assim facilmente pode atribuir á um controle ex:
            this.txtCodigoFornecedor.Text = codigo;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo segue o erro na pergunta obrigado por me ajudar

Comment: Que estranho vou verificar!

Comment: se eu fizer assim funciona que coisa de loko                                             if (retorno == DialogResult.Cancel)

Comment: Já corregi o código, tinha esquecido do DialogResult.OK, desculpas!

Comment: você é o Cara muito obrigado vai salvar a minha vida, até o final do ano vou ter muita duvida pq. estou programando sozinho no grupo e ninguem sabe e nem querem aprender mais sei que já estou aprendendo muito com isso e futuramente posso estar aqui ajudando o pessoal assim como você. Muito Obrigado

Comment: só mais uma coisa o que faz esta linha  using (var form = new frmPesquisarFornecedor())

Comment: É isso aew fera fico muito feliz em ter ajudado, com continue firme nos seus estudos que você vai longe, valeu!

Comment: O código envolvido dentro do Using serve para garantir que os objetos sejam eliminados da memoria assim que terminar a execução do mesmo, para mais informações visite esse link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx